# Доступные порты на Linux-виртуалке

Tags: linux, сокет, websocket, tcp

Имеется Linux-машина, на которой крутятся несколько других Linux-контейнеров.
Как узнать, сколько tcp-портов доступно каждому отдельному контейнеру?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/103626/292034

Comment: Из контейнера или из головной системы?

Comment: Доступно из контейнера